# Passing a boolean value to one form to another

Tags: c#

I'm trying to pass a boolean value of a checkbox to one form to another, but I want to store this value in a variable of my new form but it seems that what I code doesn't work
I know this question has been asked multiple times here but I see that the answers are more like to pass the data between objects plus I just want this boolean to be store in a new variable or a new boolean I created.

Here's the code

```
 //form 1

public partial class EcranAccueil : Form
{
  
    private bool _s;
    public bool S
    {
        get { return _s; }
        set { _s = value; }
    }

    private bool _t;
    public bool T
    {
        get { return _t; }
        set { _t = value; }
    }

    private bool _c;
    public bool C
    {
        get { return _c; }
        set { _c = value; }
    }

    private bool _dr;
    public bool DR
    {
        get { return _dr; }
        set { _dr = value; }
    }

    private bool _dd;
    public bool DD
    {
        get { return _dd; }
        set { _dd = value; }
    }
    public EcranAccueil()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void ButtonContinuer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _s = checkBoxSansDoc.Checked;
        _t = checkBoxArt.Checked;
        _c = checkBoxDocCAO.Checked;
        _dd = checkBoxDocDesc.Checked;
        _dr = checkBoxDocRef.Checked;


        Form2 f = new Form2();
        f.Show();
    }


//form2

public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public bool T_;
    public bool S_;
    public bool DD_;
    public bool DR_;
    public bool C_;

 
   public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }



private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        EcranAccueil a = new EcranAccueil();
        T_ = a.T;
        S_ = a.S;
        DD_ = a.DD;
        DR_ = a.DR;
        C_ = a.C;

     ...

     }
```

Comment: You create a new instance of `EcranAccueil` which is not related to yoour existing instance. Instead you need to pass the existing via constructor to `Form2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create a new instance of `EcranAccueil` which is not related to your existing instance. Instead you need to pass the existing via constructor to `Form2`:

```
public partial class EcranAccueil : Form
{        
    private bool _dd;
    public bool DD
    {
        get { return _dd; }
        set { _dd = value; }
    }
    // ... 

    private void ButtonContinuer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _s = checkBoxSansDoc.Checked;
        _t = checkBoxArt.Checked;
        _c = checkBoxDocCAO.Checked;
        _dd = checkBoxDocDesc.Checked;
        _dr = checkBoxDocRef.Checked;

        Form2 f = new Form2(this);
        f.Show();
    }

    // ...
    
//form2
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    EcranAccueil mainForm;
 
    public Form2(EcranAccueil mainForm)
    {
        _mainForm = mainForm;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       // you dont need the additional bool variables in this class
       // use the existing, for example _mainForm._dd;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Tim's but I usually create the constructor that takes values individually rather than the calling form. That way you can use `Form2` from other sources, such as command line or other forms types than `Form1`.

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    private bool T_;
    private bool S_;
    private bool DD_;
    private bool DR_;
    private bool C_;

    public Form2(bool t, boo, s, bool dd, bool dr, bool c)
    {
        T_=t; S_=s;DD_=dd;DR_=dr;C_=c;
    }

}
```

and call it like this

```
var Form2 f = new Form2(checkBoxArt.Checked, checkBoxSansDoc.Checked, checkBoxDocDesc.Checked, checkBoxDocRef.Checked, checkBoxDocCAO.Checked);

f.Show();
```